# One Tikz subfigure is not aligned with the others

Tags: tikz-pgf, subcaption

I created 4 TikZ pictures and used the `subcaption` package in order to obtain a 2x2 figure of the 4 pictures. However, the upper right figure is not at all aligned with the others and I don't see why.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}

\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.35\textwidth}

    \centering
    \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{

    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5]

    % Define useful points for colouring (colouring first)

    \coordinate (H1) at (0,0.9);
    \coordinate (H2) at (0.1,0.8);
    \coordinate (H3) at (0.8,0.1);
    \coordinate (H4) at (0.9,0);

    \coordinate (INTER) at (0.465,0.4);

    \coordinate (T1) at (0,0.4);
    \coordinate (T2) at (1,0.4);

    % Colouring (0,0)

    \fill[color=blue!10]
    (T1) -- (T2) -- (1,1) -- (0,1) -- cycle;

    % Box and labels

    \draw (0,0) -- (1,0) -- (1,1) -- (0,1) -- (0,0);
    \draw (0,1) node[left]{$\theta$};
    \draw (1,0) node[below]{$s$};

    % h^(-1) curve

    \draw (0,0.9) to[bend left = 5] (0.1,0.8);
    \draw (0.1,0.8) to[bend right = 5] (0.8,0.1);
    \draw (0.8,0.1) to[bend left = 5] (0.9,0);

    \draw (0.13,0.6) node {$h^{-1}(\cdot)$};

    % \t hat line

    \draw[dashed] (0,0.4) -- (1,0.4);
    \draw (0,0.4) node[left] {$\hat{\theta}$};

    % s hat line

    \draw (0.465,1) -- (0.465,0);
    \draw (0.465,0) node[below] {$\hat{s}$};

    \end{tikzpicture}

    }
    \caption{$(x_{1},x_{2}) = (0,0)$}
    \label{fig:subfigA}

\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.35\textwidth}

    \centering
    \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{

    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5]

    % Define useful points for colouring

    \coordinate (H1) at (0,0.9);
    \coordinate (H2) at (0.1,0.8);
    \coordinate (AxH2) at (0.1,1);
    \coordinate (H3) at (0.8,0.1);
    \coordinate (H4) at (0.9,0);

    \coordinate (INTER) at (0.465,0.4);
    \coordinate (AxINTER) at (0.465,1);

    \coordinate (T1) at (0,0.4);
    \coordinate (T2) at (1,0.4);

    % Colouring (1,0)

    \fill[color=blue!10]
    (0,0.9) to[bend left = 5] (0.1,0.8) -- (AxH2) -- (0,1) -- cycle;

    \fill[color=blue!10]
    (0.1,0.8) to[bend right = 5] (0.8,0.1) -- (T2) -- (1,1) -- (AxH2) -- cycle;

    \fill[color=white]
    (INTER) to[bend right = 5] (0.8,0.1) -- (T2) -- cycle;

    % Box and labels

    \draw (0,0) -- (1,0) -- (1,1) -- (0,1) -- (0,0);
    \draw (0,1) node[left]{$\theta$};
    \draw (1,0) node[below]{$s$};

    % h^(-1) curve

    \draw (0,0.9) to[bend left = 5] (0.1,0.8);
    \draw (0.1,0.8) to[bend right = 5] (0.8,0.1);
    \draw (0.8,0.1) to[bend left = 5] (0.9,0);

    \draw (0.13,0.6) node {$h^{-1}(\cdot)$};

    % \t hat line

    \draw[dashed] (0,0.4) -- (1,0.4);
    \draw (0,0.4) node[left] {$\hat{\theta}$};

    % s hat line

    \draw (0.465,1) -- (0.465,0);
    \draw (0.465,0) node[below] {$\hat{s}$};

    \end{tikzpicture}

    }
    \caption{$(x_{1},x_{2}) = (1,0)$}
    \label{fig:subfigB}

\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.35\textwidth}

    \centering
    \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{

    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5]

    % Define useful points for colouring

    \coordinate (H1) at (0,0.9);
    \coordinate (H2) at (0.1,0.8);
    \coordinate (AxH2) at (0.1,1);
    \coordinate (H3) at (0.8,0.1);
    \coordinate (AxH3) at (0.8,1);
    \coordinate (H4) at (0.9,0);

    \coordinate (INTER) at (0.465,0.4);
    \coordinate (AxINTER) at (0.465,1);

    \coordinate (T1) at (0,0.4);
    \coordinate (T2) at (1,0.4);

    % Colouring (0,1)

    \fill[color=blue!10]
    (H2) to[bend right = 5] (H3) -- (AxH3) -- (AxH2) -- cycle;

    \fill[color=blue!10]
    (H3) to[bend left = 5] (H4) -- (1,1) -- (AxH3) -- cycle;

    \fill[color=blue!10]
    (H4) to[bend left = 5] (H4) -- (1,1) -- (AxH3) -- cycle;

    \fill[color=blue!10]
    (H4) -- (1,0) -- (1,1) -- cycle;

    \fill[color=blue!10]
    (0,1) -- (0,0.4) -- (1,0.4) -- (1,1) -- cycle;

    % Box and labels

    \draw (0,0) -- (1,0) -- (1,1) -- (0,1) -- (0,0);
    \draw (0,1) node[left]{$\theta$};
    \draw (1,0) node[below]{$s$};

    % h^(-1) curve

    \draw (0,0.9) to[bend left = 5] (0.1,0.8);
    \draw (0.1,0.8) to[bend right = 5] (0.8,0.1);
    \draw (0.8,0.1) to[bend left = 5] (0.9,0);

    \draw (0.13,0.6) node {$h^{-1}(\cdot)$};

    % \t hat line

    \draw[dashed] (0,0.4) -- (1,0.4);
    \draw (0,0.4) node[left] {$\hat{\theta}$};

    % s hat line

    \draw (0.465,1) -- (0.465,0);
    \draw (0.465,0) node[below] {$\hat{s}$};

    \end{tikzpicture}

    }
    \caption{$(x_{1},x_{2}) = (0,1)$}
    \label{fig:subfigC}

\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.35\textwidth}

    \centering
    \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{

    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5]

    % Define useful points for colouring

    \coordinate (H1) at (0,0.9);
    \coordinate (H2) at (0.1,0.8);
    \coordinate (AxH2) at (0.1,1);
    \coordinate (H3) at (0.8,0.1);
    \coordinate (AxH3) at (0.8,1);
    \coordinate (H4) at (0.9,0);

    \coordinate (INTER) at (0.465,0.4);
    \coordinate (AxINTER) at (0.465,1);

    \coordinate (T1) at (0,0.4);
    \coordinate (T2) at (1,0.4);

    % Colouring (1,1)

    \fill[color=blue!10]
    (0,0.9) to[bend left = 5] (0.1,0.8) -- (AxH2) -- (0,1) -- cycle;

    \fill[color=blue!10]
    (H2) to[bend right = 5] (H3) -- (AxH3) -- (AxH2) -- cycle;

    \fill[color=blue!10]
    (H3) to[bend left = 5] (H4) -- (1,1) -- (AxH3) -- cycle;

    \fill[color=blue!10]
    (H4) to[bend left = 5] (H4) -- (1,1) -- (AxH3) -- cycle;

    \fill[color=blue!10]
    (H4) -- (1,0) -- (1,1) -- cycle;


    % Box and labels

    \draw (0,0) -- (1,0) -- (1,1) -- (0,1) -- (0,0);
    \draw (0,1) node[left]{$\theta$};
    \draw (1,0) node[below]{$s$};

    % h^(-1) curve

    \draw (0,0.9) to[bend left = 5] (0.1,0.8);
    \draw (0.1,0.8) to[bend right = 5] (0.8,0.1);
    \draw (0.8,0.1) to[bend left = 5] (0.9,0);

    \draw (0.13,0.6) node {$h^{-1}(\cdot)$};

    % \t hat line

    \draw[dashed] (0,0.4) -- (1,0.4);
    \draw (0,0.4) node[left] {$\hat{\theta}$};

    % s hat line

    \draw (0.465,1) -- (0.465,0);
    \draw (0.465,0) node[below] {$\hat{s}$};

    \end{tikzpicture}

    }
    \caption{$(x_{1},x_{2}) = (1,1)$}
    \label{fig:subfigD}

\end{subfigure}

\label{fig:EqLemma}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The result of the compilation is:
[image: compil]

I checked the many related questions and I didn't find any similar ones (but I did first the classical mistake of putting a blank line between the subfigure environments..).

Comment: You can get the same error with sample images instead of TikZ figures, so the issue has to do with `subcaption`, rather than TikZ.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To fix this, you should do two things:

1. Add a line break `\\` between your second and third subfigures.
2. Then (since this changes the horizontal alignment of the whole figure), add `\centering` just below `\begin{figure}`.

Here's what this would look like in your code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering % <-- add this

\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.35\textwidth}
  % your figure here
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.35\textwidth}
  % your figure here
\end{subfigure}
\\ % <-- add this
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.35\textwidth}
  % your figure here
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.35\textwidth}
  % your figure here
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The error has nothing to do with TikZ, and will still happen if you use example images in place of TikZ pictures.

Comment: perfect it worked ! Thanks ! However the reason is still obscure for me :)

Comment: @Yurienu : intuitively,  that is because subfigures (but also TikZ figures or `includegraphics` etc. ) are considered as boxes when the "line" is typeset. And since no linebreak was specified, your "text" made of subfigures was being justified (only on the first line, as the "paragraph" ended on the second one)

Comment: I see, good to know then ! Thanks for the explanation